# Click on TListView (on TForm) over TTreeView triggers TTreeView OnChange event

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

Using Borland C++ Builder

I have an application with a self created Breadcrumb control, positioned just above a `TTreeView` control, with `TListView` controls (`alClient` inside `TForms`) as dropdown menus.

[image]

The position of the controls is new.  Meaning, the implementation is older, and worked perfectly before, but I have only just moved the breadcrumb control above the `TTreeView` control.

And I now notice that a click on a `TListView` Item from the breadcrumb control, **also** triggers the `TTreeView` `OnChange` event !
And the selected node is the top node.

This causes a conflict in my design as both events, the `TListView` item click and the `TTreeView` `Onchange` cause different things to be displayed/done.
It's also not 100% which event ultimately 'wins' so the result is variable as well.

I can look into trying to disable `TTreeView` while the breadcrumb code is executing, so that the click is ignored, but I wonder if this is normal or if I'm missing something ?

Is it normal that both controls trigger when displayed over each other ?

The ListView item click is processed via the OnClick event that is assigned following function:

```
void __fastcall TBreadcrumbListViewEx::InternalListViewClick(TObject *Sender)
{

if (FListView->Selected && FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick)
    {
    TPoint pt;
    pt = FListView->ScreenToClient(Mouse->CursorPos);

    THitTests HitTests = FListView->GetHitTestInfoAt(pt.x, pt.y);
    if ( (HitTests.Contains(htOnIcon)) || (HitTests.Contains(htOnItem)) ||
         (HitTests.Contains(htOnLabel)) || (HitTests.Contains(htOnStateIcon)) )
        {
        // This is a very precarious situation, because the FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick callback will most likely trigger building a new Breadcrumbs layout (Different Items)
        // Which causes OnData events from this control to want to access Breadcrumbs that have been deleted already
        // Therefore, get the selected Item (which will trigger OnData) and use its Index and Data members

        TListItem *Item = FListView->Selected ;

        // Next prevent any OnData event to get through and wreak havoc
        // This needs to be done *before* Hide() is called

        _releasing = true ;

        // Hide is necesary because if the FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick event takes a long time, for instance it shows a dialog,
        // this control will still be visible, yet it cannot show proper content anymore, since the OnData event is disabled
        // Hence Hide() to no show it anymore when, for instance, a dialog is showing

        Hide() ;

        FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick(this, Item->Index, BreadcrumbItem, Item->Data);

        Release(); // Close();
        }
    }

}
```

I have been running tests.
First I disabled the event/callback `FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick()` but the problem persists, even though nothing really happens when the item is clicked.
I have been playing with disabling `Hide()`, `Release()`, replaced `Release()` with `Close()` etc.  But the problem persists if one of them is still in place.

Only when I disable both `Hide()` and `Release()`/`Close()` as well I seem not to get into trouble.  Only then I did not see the `TTreeView` `OnChange` occur anymore in my testing.  To be honest I'm not sure of anything anymore at this point.

Is this what you would expect ?  Or is this merely a side effect and the problem is still something else ?

Also ... how the hec am I going to be able to execute the callback and Hide/Remove the popup from view, without 'upsetting' `TTreeView` ?

Disabling `TTreeView` temporarily is still an option but I'd rather fix this right, not to get into trouble again next time I move the controls to a different position.

Comment: This implies that your breadcrumb code is not swallowing the mouse click on the popup Form, allowing it to pass through to the TreeView underneath. That is not how UIs operate by default, which implies your breadcrumb is likely doing something extra it should not be doing. But you have not provided a [mcve] to reproduce the problem, so I am voting to close this as off-topic.

Comment: The (ListItem) click triggers an event that re-populates the breadcrumb control.  Digging deeper I see that breadcrumb `Enabled` is set to `false` for a while, during this process, to avoid more clicks during lengthy processes.
So, this then happens during the Onclick event.  Could that be the reason why the breadcrumb control doesn't swallow the mouse click ?
I'll do some more testing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - After more testing today I felt comfortable to post code where I **think** lies the problem.  Your input appreciated.

Comment: NO.  I'm going to have to retract or redact my own answer.  While below code works better, the problem remains.  I changed my debug approach now and concentrated on `TTreeView` more than on the breadcrumb control and I noticed that the problem starts from the moment `TreeView->ClearSelection()` is called.  That call sets the TreeView in a state (Somehow) that it suddenly also captures the clicks of the control shown above it.  For situations where ClearSelection() is not called all works as expected and keeps working as expected.  Finding this explains the variability I kept seeing as well

Comment: I must assume it's a VCL issue at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up 'fixing' it by posting a message to the end of the queue, so that the `TListView` `OnClick` event can complete as fast as possible and so that the mouse event is absorbed entirely, by avoiding `Hide()` or `Release()` during the `OnClick` event.

```
void __fastcall TBreadcrumbListViewEx::InternalListViewClick(TObject *Sender)
{

if (FListView->Selected && FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick)
    {
    TPoint pt = FListView->ScreenToClient(Mouse->CursorPos);

    THitTests HitTests = FListView->GetHitTestInfoAt(pt.x, pt.y);
    if ( (HitTests.Contains(htOnIcon)) || (HitTests.Contains(htOnItem)) ||
         (HitTests.Contains(htOnLabel)) || (HitTests.Contains(htOnStateIcon)) )
        {
        PostMessage(Handle /*Destination*/, WM_APP, 0, (LPARAM)FListView->Selected);
        }
    }

}

//------------

void __fastcall TBreadcrumbListViewEx::WmApp(TMessage &Msg)
{

TListItem *ClickedItem = (TListItem*)Msg.LParam ;

if (ClickedItem)
    {

    // Next prevent any more OnData events to get through and wreak havoc
    // This needs to be done *before* Hide() is called

    _releasing = true ;

    // Hide is necesary because if the FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick event takes a long time, for instance it shows a dialog,
    // this control will still be visible, yet it cannot show proper content anymore, since the OnData event is disabled
    // Hence Hide() to no show it anymore when, for instance, a dialog is showing

    Hide() ;

    // Disable the entire breadcrumb control to avoid clicks while a dialog is up or during a lengthy process to get the data for next
    // breadcrumb layout

    BBar->Enabled = false ;

    FOnBreadcrumbListItemClick(this, ClickedItem->Index, BreadcrumbItem, ClickedItem->Data);

    BBar->Enabled = true ;

    Release();
    }

}
```